# Rails 3 and html_safe confusion (allow pictures (smiles) in chat but deny everything else)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, gsub, html-safe

I have here is a module that replaces the smilies (like ":-)") as icons:

```
module Smileize
  PATH = "/images/smiles"
  SMILES = [/\;\-?p/i, /\$\-?\)/, /8\-?\)/, /\>\:\-?\(/, /\:\-?\*/, /\:\-?o/i, /\:\-?c/i, /\;\-?\)/, 
/\:\-?s/i, /\:\-?\|/, /\:\-?p/i, /\:\-?D/i, /\:\-?\?/, /\:\-?\(/, /\:\-?\)/]
  def to_icon(key)
    return "<img class='smiley' src='#{PATH}/smile#{SMILES.index(key) + 1}.png'/>"
  end
  module_function :to_icon
end

class String
  def to_smile
    Smileize::SMILES.each do |smile|
      if self =~ smile
        self.gsub!(smile, Smileize.to_icon(smile))
      end
    end
    self
  end
end
```

So pictures show that I'm using html_safe, like this:

```
<%= @message.text.to_smile.html_safe %>
```

But it does not suit me, because but pictures will be displayed and other tags, too.

**My question is**: how to display only my smile, ignoring the other tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll need to do it like this:

1. HTML encode the string.
2. Perform your substitution.
3. Mark the final result as HTML safe.

Add a helper something like this:

```
def expand_smilies(s)
  s = ERB::Util::html_escape(s)
  Smileize::SMILES.each do |smile|
    s.gsub!(smile, Smileize.to_icon(smile))
  end
  s.html_safe
end
```

And then in your ERB:

```
<%= expand_smilies some_text %>
```

ERB uses [`ERB::Util::html_escape`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#method-c-html_escape) to encode HTML so using it yourself makes sense if you're targeting ERB. Calling [`html_safe`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-html_safe) on a string returns you something that ERB will leave alone when it is HTML encoding things.

Note that there is no usable [`html_safe!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-html_safe-21) on strings and `html_safe` returns an [ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/SafeBuffer.html) rather than a String so you'll have to use a helper rather than monkey patching a new method into String. ActiveSupport does patch an `html_safe!` method into String but all it does is raise an exception saying "don't do that":

```
def html_safe!
  raise "You can't call html_safe! on a String"
end
```